# defining grunt aliases with option values defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, alias

Does Grunt allow to define custom aliases just like npm or bash does? In [grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) it says, that one can define a sequence on tasks (which might be just a single item). So in my opinion it should be called `chaining` rather than `aliasing`. What I'm looking for is providing a grunt alias that would just define value for a parameter.

Using npm, I can make `npm test-e2e` run `grunt test --type=e2e`. In package.json I've got:

```
"scripts": {
  "test-e2e": "node_modules/.bin/grunt test --type=e2e",  
  "test-unit": "node_modules/.bin/grunt test --type=unit"
}
```

Can I make `grunt test-e2e` (notice `grunt` instead of `npm` as above) be an alias of `grunt test --type=e2e`?

Comment: Who would receive the extra parameter `type`? Usually, you would want to use a task which has different targets. There is no notion of command-line arguments being passed to tasks.

Comment: @RobertRossmann this is not an argument, it's a parameter. As far as I understand your question, it's the main task, i.e. `grunt test`. Calling `grunt test-e2e` (the alias) would *resolve* to `grunt test --type=e2e`, so the destination is `grunt test`.

Comment: What is the use-case for this? Why is having a task (or several aliases pointing to different task's targets) not suitable for you?

Comment: @RobertRossmann it's exactly the same use-case of having aliases. Less typing, more convenient (console) interface. And that's why I'm asking if it's possible to do _real_ aliases with grunt.

Comment: Well, not via Grunt API (as far as I am aware), but since a Gruntfile is just a JavaScript function, it should be possible to do pretty much anything, i.e. getting the arglist via `process.argv` and acting accordingly. Unless Grunt messes with the arguments before you get your hands on them.:)

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this as an official answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The Grunt API does not provide a way to interpret commandline arguments</strike>, but since every gruntfile is just a Node.js module, you are not restricted in any way to implement the CLI arguments interpretation yourself in the Gruntfile.

I just found out that Grunt indeed has a built-in API to retrieve CLI arguments - see the [docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) for examples on using this feature.

All arguments that are passed to a node executable are available via Node's `process.argv` array - you can either process the arguments yourself or perhaps even use one of the many argument processing modules ([minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist), [yargs](https://github.com/bcoe/yargs), [nomnom](https://github.com/harthur/nomnom) to name a few).

Comment: I think that `Grunt API does not provide a way to interpret commandline arguments` is the right answer. Grunt interprets CLI *options* but not *arguments*. If you run `grunt mytask myarg1 myarg2` then it will be interpreted the same way as `grunt mytask; grunt myarg1; grunt myarg2` and eventually throw an error _myarg1/myarg2 task not found_. And when I try to use minimist, grunt does the same as above. So it's not possible to catch arguments, because earlier they are divided into sequence of grunt tasks. I've just tried both approaches and so I'm writing the result.

Comment: Well, if arguments cannot be used, surely there must be a way to use options in your code. Perhaps `grunt mytask --myopt` will be interpreted as `grunt.option('myopt') === true` or something.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no solution for my needs (the answer is simply _no_), but I appreciate your effort Robert.